# Laravel/Eloquent Relationship Inconsistent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get information associated with an application in my database.

- Each application has 1 applicant.
- Each application has 1 puppy.

I'm returning a view with an eloquent query like this:

```
$active_applications = Application::with('applicant', 'puppy')->where('kennel_id', '=', $user_kennel->id)->get();
```

And I have some relationships defined in my application model like so:

```
public function puppy(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Puppy');
}

public function applicant(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

When the view loads, I'm able to get the information associated with 'puppy'. It retrieves properly. The applicant, however stays null.

I have, in my applications table, a column named "user_id", which I was hoping it would use value in that column to search the users table 'id', and retrieve information on the user. It stays null, however. The following is a dd() of the variable in question:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious? Why would it retrieve one and not the other?

EDIT: the puppy table
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your relation is wrong -

```
public function applicant(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

When you don't pass the foreign key as a parameter, laravel looks for the `method name` + `'_id'`. Therefore in your case laravel is looking for the column `applicant_id` in your application table.

So, to get results there are two ways -

**1) You need to either change your method name -**

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**2) Pass foreign key as the second parameter - **

```
public function applicant(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

> > **Laravel 5.6 doc - *belongsTo***
>
> If its a **One to Many(Inverse) Relation** -
>
> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name
> of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a _
> followed by the name of the primary key column.
>
> If its a **One to One Relation** -
>
> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name
> of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.

[Review Laravel doc for more details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

Comment: Thank you sir, that worked perfectly. I didn't realize it used the function name as the string for table matching. I thought it took the model name. Cheers

Comment: Always happy to help a fellow developer ;) Cheers and happy coding.

Comment: That makes sense. But I wonder, why OPs code didn't thow an exception, since there is no `applicant_id` column in the table.

Comment: Your comment about the `method name` + `_id` is wrong. Straight from the docs: `By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id`.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan **You are stating the documentation for `hasMany` and not `belongsTo`.** Please check the documentation first.

For `belongs to` laravel doc says - Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan - Your quote is for a `hasMany` relation. For `belongsTo` you will find "Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a _ followed by the name of the primary key column."

Comment: @PaulSpiegel My bad! Nothing to see here, move along xD. Upvote for your solution!

Comment: @thebrownkid - Interesting. The documentation is not consistent. They say different things for *One To One* and *Many To One* (*One To Many (Inverse)*). Though both use `belongsTo()`. However - there is no difference when the primary key is `id`.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Not sure if we are looking at the same place or maybe it's my sleep deprived eyes but the documentation is saying the same thing for both _One to One_ and _Many to One_. The `belongsTo` foreign key naming is being done the same way in both. Can you please be specific so I can take a look.

Comment: @thebrownkid I was looking at the `one to many` [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). The part I quoted is right beneath the first example.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Haa... never realized as the usual primary key is _id_. Good spot!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line instead:

```
$active_applications = Application::with(['applicant', 'puppy'])->where('kennel_id', '=', $user_kennel->id)->get();
```

As far as I know, multiple "with" should be passed as array.

Adjust the relationship as well

```
public function applicant(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried sticking them into an array, and applicant remains null.

Comment: Check my revised message.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct -- each application belongs to one applicant. Since one user can have many applications, the application BELONGS to the user. I initially tried it your way (hasOne) and it threw errors of can't find column id 'application_id' in the users table.

Comment: Right, does every application has an associated user? could you also show the puppy table?

Comment: Yes, every application has an associated user. I just checked the application that I'm using and it has a value (18) for its user_id column. There is also a user 18 in the users table. I edited to include the puppy table, see above.

Comment: Try to be more specific with the belongs to, see if that might work